# Subselect and ldaHmat error: Arguments of wrong type

Tags: r, lda, simulated-annealing

I'm trying to use the subselect library and the anneal function to find a minimal subset of a larger dataset that can be used to predict a condition.  Whenever I run the ldaHmat command, however, I get the error that the arguments are of the wrong type:

DataHmat <- ldaHmat(TrimmedData[1:569],TrimmedData$Condition)

where TrimmedData is a df where for columns 1 to 569 many of the values are 0 but many are also non-zero (e.g. 0.0169) and TrimmedData$Condition is a text value (e.g. "control" or "disease").  Even a small subset of this (e.g. 1:5) gives me this error - and I'm not sure what "arguments are of the wrong type" is even trying to tell me!

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

And realized what the mistake was.  The Condition column was of type integer and not factor!  I had to do this:

TrimmedData$Condition <- factor(TrimmedData$Condition)

And now everything (well, at least that part) works fine.